# Coverage metrics do not consider code without tests?

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

In a project where some components have test coverage and others don't it seems that SonarQube only calculates the total code coverage based on the components that have coverage. I would expect that the lines of code in components without test coverage are classified (at least for calculations) as having 0% code coverage.

**Example:**

- Project X

  - Module 1: 100% coverage
  - Module 2: N/A coverage (I reason that this is equivalent to 0% in a computation!)

SonarQube coverage (Project X): 100%

**How is the total coverage calculated? If this is by design, why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coverage is calculated based on the lines covered during test execution. If you have no test, test execution is skipped, no code is executed at all and therefore no coverage data is produced. So there is a difference between *N/A* and *0%*

If you add an empty test to the module, it will be used for calculation and produce 0% coverage as result.

**EDIT:**
Assuming you are using Jacoco for coverage. Jacoco write the coverage information into a file (i.e. `jacoco.exec`). For unit tests (maven surefire) this file is written to the target directory of the module and coverage is calculated for that module using that file. No file, no coverage.

When I run integration tests, I want to determine what parts of the code of the entire project is covered by a tests. My integration tests are typically located in separate module as well. So per-module coverage doesn't make much sense in that case, because test (1 module) and product (all other modules) are sparated.
So I run the integration tests and write the coverage information into a single `jacoco-it.exec` file into the target folder of the root module (project). As a result, the coverage for the entire code base is calculated, including modules with 0% coverage (See here for how to set it up: [Multi-Module Integration Test Coverage with Jacoco and Sonar](http://whoopdicity.blogspot.ch/2015/05/multi-module-integration-test-coverage.html))

What you loose with this approach is, what parts of code of a single module are covered by tests of that single module. Because parts of a module can be covered by tests of another module, i.e. coverage of a module can be 30% without having any test in that module.

So you have the choice:

- detailed coverage per module, with test-less modules having N/A coverage
- total coverage for entire project, with test-less modules having 0% coverage but without exact coverage information by module
- both: using both approaches for unit test and integration tests separately

Comment: Hi, I understand the difference and it makes perfect sense to visualize 0 and N/A differently but when summarizing coverage it is very easy to draw the wrong conclusion if "skipping" modules without coverage. As a developer I would look at the numbers and say: "Yeah, we have good coverage, nothing to do here."

If calculated as I propose one would see that the coverage is low and then investigate this further and see that there are modules without coverage

Comment: you need to calculate the coverage for the entire project then, but you loose the information by module, I edited response accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I will accept this answer even though I'm not completely satisfied how this is handled by SonarQube. It would be good to have some sort of indication that the coverage data is incomplete or similar.

Comment: It is now possible, for several language plugins in SonarQube, to declare whether no coverage should be interpreted as 0% coverage. Thanks for this (SonarSource)! Please add it to all language plugins (not possible for e.g. the C/C++/Objective-C plugin as of version 5.6.5 LTS)

Comment: Alix, could you please point me to some documentation about this feature?

Comment: use this flag `-Dsonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero=true`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46151209/3985482