# How to force code coverage to Zero?

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

I have several java projects with no unit test cases. When I try to analyse these projects using SonarQube I am unable to get unit test code coverage because it doesn't have any test cases. As per my research I saw that I can force it to show it as zero if there are no unit test cases. The [official Jacoco Java documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin) mentions `sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero=true`.

My SonarQube analysis will be done using maven builds and SonarQube 5.6.6 and sonar-java 4.11.0.10660.

How can I set this parameter in maven so that it can show as zero unit test cases in my coverage?

Answer (score 1):

From version 6.2 SonarQube does this automatically where the behavior is supported by the analyzers. Before that version, availability of the feature is spotty and not entirely reliable. For best results you should upgrade SonarQube.

That said, you can set that property on the analysis command line like so:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero=true
```

Or by setting a property in your pom, as [shown in the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-ConfiguringtheSonarQubeAnalysis)

**Update 16 Dec 2019**
Most language analyzers now calculate [Executable Lines](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/executable-lines/), so files omitted from the coverage report are included in calculations anyway. But that only kicks in if you provide coverage reports. No coverage reports -> no coverage metrics at all.

Comment: Thanks Ann, but this error got popped up when I tried to do using given command `[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero=true". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-i
d>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>`

Comment: unfortunately, `sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero=true` is already deprecated as of **SonarQube 7.9** now @g-ann-sonarsource-team